# Double pointers to add an element to a linked list

Tags: c, singly-linked-list, double-pointer

So I'm trying to add a card to a player's hand... and the value of the card will only be passed back to the main function if I use a double pointer for the top and last cards. But last->pt can't translate to temp, how do I fix this?

```
typedef struct card_s
{
char suit[9];
int value;
struct card_s *pt;
} card;

void deal_card(card **top, card **last, card dealt)
{
card *temp;

temp = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card));
strcpy(temp->suit, dealt.suit);
temp->value = dealt.value;

if(*top == NULL)
    *top = temp;
else
    *last->pt = temp; //FIX ME - something is going wrong at this point
*last = temp;
last->pt = NULL; //FIX ME - same problem as above
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be operator precedence, so using parentheses should resolve it:

```
(*last)->pt = temp;
```

The way it was written originally, it was treating `last` as a (single) pointer, and trying to dereference member `pt`. Instead, you want to dereference `last`, and then access member `pt` of the resulting pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Since pointers to structures are common, and the parentheses in the example above are a nuisance, there's another structure selection operator which works on pointers to structures. If p is a pointer to a structure and m is a member of that structure, then

```
p->m
```

selects that member of the pointed-to structure. The expression p->m is therefore exactly equivalent to

```
(*p).m
```

You on the other hand are using some vague combination. Use either format.
E.g. `last->pt` or `(*last).pt`

Also these lines contain asterisks that don't belong there I believe:

```
if(*top == NULL)
    *top = temp;
else
    *last->pt = temp; //FIX ME - something is going wrong at this point
*last = temp;
```

All together, this should work:

```
if(top == NULL)
    top = temp;
else
    last->pt = temp;
last = temp;
```

(Assuming you want to change the address the pointer is pointing to. If you use a asterisk in front of it you are comparing/assigning with the actual value the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: The type of `last` is `card **`, so surely `last->pt` would be trying to access a member of a pointer (`card *`) rather than a member of the structure (`card`)?